# rails passing null values when creating using AR create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, octopus

In my rails application, I have a button which when clicked, copies data from one database and insert it in another.

I am using octopus gem to link my application to 2 databases.

To copy a record  from db_A to db_B, I am using the code below:

```
Octopus.using(:shard_B) do
    @book_new_live = Book.create(
      :BK_SUB_FK => @book.BK_SUB_FK,
      :BK_TITLE => @book.BK_TITLE,
      :BK_SOURCE => "",
      :BK_PUB => "",
      :BK_COVER => "",
      :BK_LABEL_PRODUCT => @book.BK_LABEL_PRODUCT,
      :BK_FINAL_LABEL => "",
      :BK_VISUAL_METHOD => @book.PRB_VISUAL_METHOD,
      :BK_DB => "",
      :BK_COVERED_REGION => "",
      :BK_VERSION_NO => @book.BK_VERSION_NO,
      :BK_SEQ_FILE => "",
      )do |primary|
      primary.BK_ID = @book.BK_ID
    end
end
```

Database 'db_b', to which data in copied, does not accept null values and the columns cannot be null and the default value is 'NONE'.

Also, I am not allowed to modify the structure of the database so that it can accept null values.

If I use the simplified code below, I get an error message which informs me that the columns 'BK_SOURCE', 'BK_PUB', 'BK_COVER'...cannot be null. By default rails is passing null to those columns.

So I have to pass empty strings to the columns which cannot be null.

```
Octopus.using(:shard_B) do
    @book_new_live = Book.create(
      :BK_SUB_FK => @book.BK_SUB_FK,
      :BK_TITLE => @book.BK_TITLE,
      :BK_LABEL_PRODUCT => @book.BK_LABEL_PRODUCT,
      :BK_VISUAL_METHOD => @book.PRB_VISUAL_METHOD,
      :BK_VERSION_NO => @book.BK_VERSION_NO,
      )do |primary|
      primary.BK_ID = @book.BK_ID
    end
end
```

Is there a way of preventing rails from passing null values to the columns not mentioned in the above code?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you can just use the `or` operator to send your values like this:

```
Octopus.using(:shard_B) do
  @book_new_live = Book.create(
    :BK_SUB_FK => @book.BK_SUB_FK,
    :BK_TITLE => @book.BK_TITLE,
    :BK_SOURCE => @book.BK_SOURCE || "NONE",
    :BK_PUB => @book.BK_PUB || "NONE",
    :BK_COVER => @book.BK_COVER || "NONE",
    :BK_LABEL_PRODUCT => @book.BK_LABEL_PRODUCT,
    :BK_FINAL_LABEL => "",
    :BK_VISUAL_METHOD => @book.PRB_VISUAL_METHOD,
    :BK_DB => "",
    :BK_COVERED_REGION => "",
    :BK_VERSION_NO => @book.BK_VERSION_NO,
    :BK_SEQ_FILE => "",
    )do |primary|
    primary.BK_ID = @book.BK_ID
  end
end
```

By saying that the value to be passed is `@book.BK_SOURCE || "NONE"`, if the attribute is `nil`, then the string `NONE` is passed instead.

**EDIT**

```
hash = {
  :BK_SUB_FK => @book.BK_SUB_FK,
  :BK_TITLE => @book.BK_TITLE,
  :BK_SOURCE => @book.BK_SOURCE,
  :BK_PUB => @book.BK_PUB,
  :BK_COVER => @book.BK_COVER,
  :BK_LABEL_PRODUCT => @book.BK_LABEL_PRODUCT,
  :BK_FINAL_LABEL => @book.BK_FINAL_LABEL,
  :BK_VISUAL_METHOD => @book.PRB_VISUAL_METHOD,
  :BK_DB => @book.BK_DB,
  :BK_VERSION_NO => @book.BK_VERSION_NO
}
hash = hash.delete_if { |k, v| v.nil? }
Octopus.using(:shard_B) do
  @book_new_live = Book.create(hash)do |primary|
    primary.BK_ID = @book.BK_ID
  end
end
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would like to keep my code simple and not include the columns for which I have no data for e.g 'BK_DB'. Is there a way of setting the rails app to pass 'None' as default instead of null?

Comment: Well then. The `create` method accepts a `hash` to be passed on. So if you apply a `delete_if` on your hash, making the condition be "remove all nil values", then i believe it would work. I'll edit the answer with some sample code.